# jquery start timer runs very fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery function to play a count down timer but some times after some interval seconds hand goes very fast as a result time finish in much less than defined time.

This is my code:

```
function runTimer(){

    total_seconds = 59;
    total_minutes = parseInt($("body").data("exam_time")) - 1;

    examTimer = setInterval(function(){
        $('.countMinutes').find('.digit').html(total_minutes + '<small> mins</small>');
        $('.countSeconds').find('.digit').html(total_seconds + '<small> sec</small>');
        total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
        if(parseInt(total_seconds) <= 0){
            total_minutes = total_minutes - 1;
            total_seconds = 60;
        }
        if(parseInt(total_minutes) == 5){

            if($("body").data("popUpRemaining") == "true"){
                popUpNot('error','Less than five minutes remaining');
                $("body").data("popUpRemaining","false");
            }
        }
        if(parseInt(total_minutes) <= -1){
            finishExam('timeOver');
            clearInterval(examTimer);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: can you create fiddle of the same ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is there another timer running on your page? Even though the names are different they could mess each other up if one was not cleared correctly

Comment: Avoid [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Dangerous_usage), instead would be better if you recursively call [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no i have only one runtimer function and its called on only sigle startExam() function

Comment: @Givi can u suggest ne fiddle of it

Comment: Here is a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/R7765/1/)**

Comment: Look at: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/DVPLp/)

Comment: @givi i am calling it in same way but on on button click,i am calling runTimer() inside other function in which returned minut and second class is used to show time left

Comment: If an answer solved your problem it would be nice, to mark it as `accepted`. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would expect, that you run 'runTimer()' function twice somewhere. For example, it is on click listener and you click twice, or you bind it as on click listener twice and it starts twice after just one click.

The second idea is that, since your counter are global variables maybe you used the same names somewhere else (in other function).

Answer (score 1):

This is hard for the people here to reproduce, if you cannot provide it as a sample. Due your reputation does not allow Links atm, please reduce your code to a working short example, which you can put here. Maybe while reducing you will notice the error by yourself (I did several times =)

Now to your code:

- use jQuery caching, and do not reselect the elements every time. This saves performance
- scope variables correctly to prevent accidental modifications (e.g. like below - might not work like that!)

  ```
  function runTimer(){

      var $body = $('body');
      var $min = $('.countMinutes .digit');
      var $sec = $('.countSeconds .digit');

      var total_seconds = 59;
      var total_minutes = parseInt($body.data("exam_time")) - 1;

      var examTimer = setInterval(function(){
          $min.html(total_minutes + '<small> mins</small>');
          $sec.html(total_seconds + '<small> sec</small>');
          total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
          if (parseInt(total_seconds) <= 0){
              total_minutes = total_minutes - 1;
              total_seconds = 60;
          }
          if (parseInt(total_minutes) == 5){
              if ($body.data("popUpRemaining") == "true"){
                  popUpNot('error','Less than five minutes remaining');
                  $body.data("popUpRemaining","false");
              }
          }
          if (parseInt(total_minutes) <= -1){
              finishExam('timeOver');
              clearInterval(examTimer);
          }
      },1000);

  }
  ```
- do not use complicated switch logic for time. In your case use just seconds and calculate the minutes, this will make it more easy to understand and reduces errors.

  ```
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  function runTimer(){

      var totalSec = 600; // 10 min
      var digitMin = Math.floor(totalSec / 60);
      var digitSec = totalSec % 60;

      totalSec++;
      var timer = setInterval(function(){
          totalSec -= 1;
          digitMin = Math.floor(totalSec / 60);
          digitSec = totalSec % 60;
          if (totalSec == 0){
              clearInterval(timer);
          }

          body.innerText = digitMin +':'+ digitSec;
      },1000);

  }
  runTimer();
  ```

  **http://jsfiddle.net/Lsrxh/**